# Publishing an image from disk

Tags: ros, opencv2, publish, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

What's te best way to solely stream an image from disk? How do I convert from cv::Mat to proper ROS image message?

The relevant snippet would be:

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
cv_ptr->image = cv::imread(this->filename_);
image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
```

How can the cv_bridge::CvImagePtr be initialized? The command above aborts at runtime as one would expect if the constructor requires something else. The error:

```
iri_simple_perception: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr< <template-parameter-1-1> >::operator->() const [with T = cv_bridge::CvImage]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

Having a look at toCvCopyImpl seems a bit of an overkill ( http://www.ros.org/doc/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/cv__bridge_8cpp_source.html#l00200 ). So, any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11550/publishing-an-image-from-disk/) by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2011-10-14

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cv_bridge::CvImagePtr is a *pointer* type that points to `NULL` by default. You have to allocate storage before you can actually use it, and the boost assertion catches the null pointer dereference.

Correct would be either something like

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr(new cv_bridge::CvImage);
```

or

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
cv_ptr.reset (new cv_bridge::CvImage);
```

As a rule of thumb, every ROS type `xxxPtr` is a pointer type for `xxx`.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2011-10-24**:
There was a bug, it perfectly works now.

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2011-10-18**:
Yes, I did.  image_transport::Publisher pub = imgtransport_.advertise("disk/image", 1);

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-10-17**:
Did you advertise the publisher properly? It is not sufficient just to declare a Publisher image_pub_, you must call ImageTransport::advertise() or something similar to get a valid Publisher object.

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2011-10-16**:
I'll mark the question as unresolved, in case somebody steps up to this alternative approach.

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2011-10-14**:
Yes, that looks more like what I was thinking of. There's, however, something I'm still missing: a fatal is reported by the publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg()). 'Call to publish() on an invalid image_transport::Publisher'. I've tried both filling the header and encoding as well as leaving them blank.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used the [gscam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam) driver to publish saved video files as a camera, and you can also use it to do snapshots, or really anything that gstreamer supports. You would be able to do what you want using this driver.

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2011-10-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2011-10-14**:
Indeed it works! Thanks!

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-10-14**:
It will be the same syntax as the gst-launch command. Store the command you used to the gst-launch (without the sink) to the environment variable GSCAM_CONFIG. See the wiki for details.

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2011-10-14**:
Looks good. Although I am not familiar with the syntax, I've managed to publish the image through gst-launch. I'll look into it to port it to the gscam config export definition. Or you do know what that would be?

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2011-10-14**:
Sure, however you'll have to adjust the gstreamer pipeline to constantly publish the same image.

**Comment by [quimnuss](https://answers.ros.org/users/663/quimnuss/) on 2011-10-14**:
Would it work with a single still jpg image?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my example that I got working in Hydro

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

    cv_bridge::CvImage cv_image;
    cv_image.image = cv::imread("/home/taylor/Pictures/face.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv_image.encoding = "bgr8";
    sensor_msgs::Image ros_image;
    cv_image.toImageMsg(ros_image);

  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("/static_image", 1);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(5);

  while (nh.ok()) 
  {
    pub.publish(ros_image);
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) with karma: 385 on 2014-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2015-07-13**:
Thank you very much! This code is excellent!